# Installling phpunit mac osx snowleopard (zend framework)

Tags: macos, zend-framework, phpunit

I'v been trying to get phpunit up and running but for some reason i'm stuck with the following  error:

Warning: require(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 44

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 44

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include path is not setup. Follow the instructions at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Also check if you installed phpunit in the correct directory:

```
$ pear list-files phpunit/phpunit
```

`PHPUnit/Autoload.php` should be listed there, in the patch you added to the include path.

---

Update: the problem was that @Peter had **2** php.ini files, and he edited the wrong one.

Find the correct one with

```
$ php --ini
```

Comment: I added the include path in the php.ini and when I open zendserver CE it shows the path but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: In the list which the "$ pear list-files..." command returns is a line: php   /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php. I assume that's right. But still the same.

Comment: what is your exact include path now?

Comment: It's: ".:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/share/pear"

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean but in the "/usr/share/pear"  directory is the "PHPUnit/Autoload.php".

Comment: You wrote in your question: `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:')`, which means the include path is not setup correctly. After you changed it, does that error message show the correct include path? Please update your question.

Comment: The error is exactly the same? Is it possible that Phpunit uses an other php.ini?

Comment: might be. run `php --ini` to find out.

Comment: Finally!, The problem was that there were two php executables and one php.ini the one that got loaded was not the one with the php.ini so i removed the one in /usr/bin/ and replaced it with the one in the zend folder. And Voila! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Irakli's post was the most helpful.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.2 and I use Homebrew to install packages. Homebrew put php in /usr/local/bin/php.

Following Irakli's hint that phpunit is using a different version on of PHP (even though it was using the same php.ini file), I edited /usr/bin/phpunit, replacing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

with this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
```

(Irakli's suggestion of "#!/usr/bin/env php" didn't work for me)

Now phpunit can find "File/Iterator/Autoload.php" which is was having trouble with before, so I guess it's in the path now.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac Lion I added the include path:

```
/usr/lib/php/pear/
```

to `/private/etc/php.ini` which solved the error.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (e.g. when using brew-installed PHP on OS-X Leopard/Snow Leopard/Lion) the problem can be that there're multiple php versions installed and phpunit is picking wrong one.

There's an easy solution, sudo-edit /usr/bin/phpunit and replace `#!/usr/bin/php` with `#!/usr/bin/env php`

Somebody should probably submit a bug to phpunit, referring to PHP executable directly is really careless.

Comment: Sir, I had to use /usr/local/bin/php to get this to work. I'm guessing homebrew has switched the location of php since this was posted.